# Magento 2 in subfolder Nginx

Tags: magento, nginx

Using Nginx 1.4.6 on Ubuntu, i'm trying to configure Magento 2 to run in a subfolder.

I already have some others projets in `/var/www`, that are set up like so:

```
server {
    server_name website.com;

    root /var/www/;

    location /p1/ {
        # config
    }

    location /p2/ {
        # config
    }
}
```

But now, my Magento installation is located at `/mnt/storage/demo/demo-magento2` and I can't find a way to include it in this server block.

I tried to use their sample configuration for Nginx (https://github.com/magento/magento2/wiki/Nginx-Configuration-Settings-and-Environment-Variables). So, I added this location block to my server block configuration:

```
location /demos/demo-magento2/ {
  set $MAGE_ROOT /mnt/storage/demo-magento2/;
  set $MAGE_MODE developers;
  include /mnt/storage/demo-magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

And Nginx keeps returning me this error:

```
2015/10/19 18:15:04 [emerg] 6250#0: location "/setup" is outside location "/demos/demo-magento2/" in /mnt/storage/demo-magento2/nginx.conf.sample:27
```

I am quite new to Nginx, so can someone explains me how to figure it out?

Comment: you say it is located in `/mnt/storage/demo/demo-magento2` but in your location block you declare `/mnt/storage/demo-magento2/`, there is a mismatch already there. correct it already, maybe that's it

Comment: also it says you have to heve at least Nginx 1.8 or higher

Comment: @Memes damn, that was it, thanks! (sorry for the late reply btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Memes pointed out, I made a mistake in my location block:

```
location /demos/demo-magento2/ {
  set $MAGE_ROOT /mnt/storage/demo-magento2/;
  set $MAGE_MODE developers;
  include /mnt/storage/demo-magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Should be:

```
location /demos/demo-magento2/ {
  set $MAGE_ROOT /mnt/storage/demo/demo-magento2/;
  set $MAGE_MODE developers;
  include /mnt/storage/demo/demo-magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

The key is that I was missing the demo/ subfolder in the path. 
The nginx error was actually pretty self-explanatory!

Answer (score 2):

Nginx configuration is picky about where directives are located; because Magento's nginx.conf.sample contains 'location' directives, it must be included from inside a "server" directive. Take a look at the commented out portion at the top of the sample config; it shows roughly what the main configuration file should like.

You should have a root configuration file which looks like this:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.dev;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /path/to/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /path/to/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
 }
```

And if you're using the typical Ubuntu-nginx setup, you'll want that file under the /etc/nginx/sites-available directory, and to enable it you'd want to create a  symlink to that file from the sites-enabled directory.